# Getting data back from an NSURLSession via POST with JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios9, nsurlsession

Since NSURLConnection is depreated I need to move to an NSURLSession.  I have a URL and some data I need to input as JSON.  Then the result should be JSON coming back. I see something like so:

```
NSError *error;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"[JSON SERVER"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"TEST IOS", @"name",
                     @"IOS TYPE", @"typemap",
                     nil];
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

I this the correct approach?

My requirements are:
1. Turn my key value pairs into JSON.
2. Pass in the URL and JSON to a reusable function.
3. Get the JSON data returned.
4. Parse the JSON data returned.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using Alamofire?  It makes networking quite simple.  Have you tried your code above?  Is it working?  You didn't really ask a real question here short of wanting somebody to copy/paste your code and test it.  As to "Is this the correct approach?" I'd be a smart alec and say no, migrate to Swift :)

Comment: Looks okay to me.  Are you having trouble with it?  Do steps 3 & 4 in the completionHandler.  Consider giving the method where this code appears a completion block, too, so callers can get the result asynchronously.

Comment: I agree w danh. BTW, if you're doing multiple requests, I'd also encourage you to not instantiate a new session object each time. Instantiate the session object once. Also, are you really implementing delegate methods? If not, I'd just instantiate with `sessionWithConfiguration` with no `delegate` nor `delegateQueue`, or perhaps use `sharedSession`. That's up to you.

Comment: If you're not modifying the session configuration in any way and you're not using a delegate, you should use the shared session.  That's what it is intended for.  Basically, it acts like NSURLConnection....

Comment: @danh and Rob what's the syntax to create a block if say I put this in a method call - (void) getAPI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the callers to your method to provide a completion handler which processes the data returned and update the UI to indicate completion.

You can copy the pattern found in the SDK, as follows:

```
- (void)makeRequest:(NSString *)param completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary *, NSError *))completion;
```

Implement it like this:

```
// in the same scope
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

- (void)makeRequest:(NSString *)param
         completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary *, NSError *))completion {

    // your OP code goes here, e.g.
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = // maybe the param is the url for this request
   // use the already initialized session
    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request 
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        // call the completion handler in EVERY code path, so the caller is never left waiting
        if (!error) {
            // convert the NSData response to a dictionary
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
            if (error) {
                // there was a parse error...maybe log it here, too
                completion(nil, error);
            } else {
                // success!
                completion(dictionary, nil);
            }
        } else {
            // error from the session...maybe log it here, too
            completion(nil, error);
        }
    }];
    [postDataTask resume];
}
```

Code that calls this method will look like this:

```
// update the UI here to say "I'm busy making a request"
// call your function, which you've given a completion handler
[self makeRequest:@"https://..." completion:^(NSDictionary *someResult, NSError *error) {
    // here, update the UI to say "Not busy anymore"
    if (!error) {
        // update the model, which should cause views that depend on the model to update
        // e.g. [self.someUITableView reloadData];
    } else {
        // handle the error
    }
}];
```

Notice a couple things: (1) the return type is `void`, the caller expects nothing to be returned from this method, and makes no assignment when calling it.  The data "returned" is provided as parameters to the completion handler, which is called later, after the asnych request is complete, (2) the signature of the completion handler matches exactly what the caller declared in the completion block `^(NSDictionary *, NSError *)`, this is just a suggestion, typical for network requests.

Answer (score 3):

1. Instantiate the `NSURLSession` and `NSMutableURLRequest` object:

   ```
   NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
   NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
   ```
2. Turn your key value pairs into JSON:

   ```
   // choose the right type for your value.
   NSDictionary *postDict = @{@"key1": value1, @"key2": value2};
   NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict options:0 error:nil];
   ```
3. Make your POST with with the URL and JSON:

   ```
   [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"JSON SERVER"];
   [request setHTTPBody:postData];
   NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

   }];
   [postDataTask resume];
   ```
4. Parse the JSON data returned **within** the `completionHandler` above:

   ```
   if (!error) {                        
       NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
   } else {
       // error code here
   }
   ```

   `responseDict` is the parsed data. For example, if the server returns

   ```
   {
       "message":"Your messsage",
       "data1":value1,
       "data2":value2
   }
   ```

   You can easily get the value for `data1` by using

   ```
    [responseDict objectForKey:@"data1"];
   ```

If your want to make another POST with different URL or JSON, just repeat the flow of step 2-4.

Hope my answer helps.

Comment: Explained very well. Thank you!!